# How to execute Jquery onclick="" function only after JS validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wonder if I can execute onlick function only after JS validation any ideas?

I have a form which has e-amil and phone mandatory filed and i would like to check them before form is submitted , even more if everything is ok another div `onclick="$('#dialog-links-blocks').show()"` should be display with a message Thank you! How can I make it to be shown only after validation !

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myform"]["phone"].value;
var y=document.forms["myform"]["email"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("Укажите номер телефона!");
  return false;
  }
if (y==null || y=="")
  {
  alert("Укажите email!");
  return false;
  }

}
// ]]></script>


<iframe name="hiddenFrame" width="320" height="240"></iframe>
<form id="validation" action="http://listovki.md/send_form_email.php" method="POST" name="myform" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validateForm()" target="hiddenFrame">
    <table><colgroup> <col width="122" /> <col width="260" /> </colgroup>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td><label>имя</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="family" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><label>почта</label></td>
    <td><input type="email" name="email" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><label>gsm</label></td>
    <td><input class="gsm" type="tel" name="phone" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><input class="aplicaAcumBt" onclick="$('#dialog-links-blocks').show()" type="submit" name="submit" value="отправить" /></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: you can't because the click event of the submit button will fire before the submit event of the form is fired.... you can rearrange the code so that the code is executed after the validation

Comment: if you want to go with inlined event handler(not recommended) then try `<form id="validation" action="http://listovki.md/send_form_email.php" method="POST" name="myform" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="if(!validateForm()){return false;}$('#dialog-links-blocks').show();" target="hiddenFrame">` and remove the onclick handler

Comment: validation is ok but div block doesn't show up :(

Comment: may is better to arrange it in one Jquery code?

Comment: You could use jQuery validation plugin to validate your inputs right after they were filled. (http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not show div only if validation is true? why show only on click

```
    <script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
    function validateForm()
    {
    var x=document.forms["myform"]["phone"].value;
    var y=document.forms["myform"]["email"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
      {
      alert("Укажите номер телефона!");
      return false;
      }
    if (y==null || y=="")
      {
      alert("Укажите email!");
      return false;
      }
    // Validation is true here
    $('#dialog-links-blocks').show()
    }
    </script>
```